# Solidity inherited constructors and calling the parent constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I'm trying to inherit from a contract.  I'm expecting the child contract to have the same constructor as the parent (or be overwritten)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract parent{
    string public name;
    function parent(string _name){
        name=_name;
    }
}

contract child is parent{}
```

If I try

```
contract child2 is parent{
    function child2(string _name){
        name=_name;
    }
}
```

Then the string entered at construction, that should go into name, doesn't get stored.

What's going on?  How do constructors work with inheritance?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The trick is in the definition of the interface for `Child`'s constructor.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Parent {
    
    bytes32 public name;
    
    function parent(bytes32 _name){
        name=_name;
    }
}


contract Child is Parent {
    
    function child(bytes32 _name) parent(_name) {}
    
}
```

An explanation of this syntax here: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 26):

Solidity 0.5+ has a different syntax for calling parent constructors.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;


contract Parent {

    public string name;

    constructor(string _name) {
        name = _name;
    }
}

contract Child is Parent {

    constructor() Parent("Guybrush Threepwood")  {
         // Child construction code goes here
    }
}
```