# This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created. for myfirstcontract contract Bank is working

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Bank {
    uint private value;


    function Bank(uint amount) {
        value = 10;
    }

    function deposit(uint amount) {
        value += amount;
    }


    function balance() constant returns (uint) {
        return value;
    }

}

contract MyFirstContract is Bank {
    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    function getName() returns (string) {
        return name;
    }

    function setAge(uint newAge) {
        age = newAge;
    }

    function getAge() returns (uint) {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child contract does not have a constructor which would call the `Bank`'s constructor. As the `Bank` contract has a constructor (with parameters), you have to call it in child contracts.

So adding something like this at the beginning of your child contract will make it deploy:

```
constructor() Bank(1) {

}
```

Of course you should decide on the exact logic, but hopefully you get the point.

P.S. Is is strongly encouraged to use the keyword `constructor` for a constructor. The way you are defining your constructor will not be allowed anymore in Solidity version 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up a lot of warnings by adding `public` to each function.

In `Bank` your constructor accepts a `uint` argument:

`function Bank(uint amount)`

Since `MyFirstContract is Bank` you need to define how this value will passed in. For example, add a constructor:

`constructor() Bank(0) {}`

If you want, you can pass the argument in and pass it through to `Bank`.

`constructor(uint arg1) Bank(arg1) {}`

Have a look over here for a more detailed explanation of what's going on here. [Inherited Constructors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16318/inherited-constructors/16322#16322)

Hope it helps.