# Solidity Syntax question

Tags: solidity, erc-20, inheritance, constructor

What happens if a function is being passed before `{` into another function?

Like `DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, TOKEN_DECIMALS)` in this example:

```
function MyToken(Registry _registry, string _name, string _symbol) public
    DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, TOKEN_DECIMALS)
{
    require(_registry != address(0));

    registry = _registry;
}
```

Would this be the same as above:

```
function MyToken(Registry _registry, string _name, string _symbol) public
{
    DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, TOKEN_DECIMALS)
    require(_registry != address(0));

    registry = _registry;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `constructor` in the old syntax. The name, `MyToken` matches the name of the contract and this is therefore considered the constructor. Like this:

```
contract MyToken {
  function MyToken( ...
```

This is the old system. This caused some errors on the part of developers, so more recent compilers use the `constructor` keyword, like this:

```
contract MyToken {
  constructor(...
```

Construtors are like `init()` in other languages. They run exactly one time during deployment. They cannot run again and because of this, the constructor bytecode isn't even stored.

The pattern you see also uses inheritance and arguments passed into constructors. Suppose you have a contract `DetailedERC20` and it's constructor takes some arguments (`_name, _symbol, TOKEN_DECIMALS)`

You also have `MyToken` and it inherits from the first, like:

```
contract MyToken is DetailedERC20 { ...
```

`MyToken` has a constructor that is taking some arguments. Some of those arguments need to passed through to `DetailedERC20`'s constructor so it will know what to do.

The first set of arguments `(Registry _registry, string _name, string _symbol)` is declaring the function signature. Notice all the variables are typed. The second one is scooping up some of the defined inputs and passing them into the inherited constructor.

There is another example/explanation over here: [Inherited Constructors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16318/inherited-constructors)

Hope it helps.

Comment: So `Inherited Constructor` is the keyword. Thank you very much, that makes sense to me! Would an inherited constructor look in the new syntax the same?

Comment: Is the inherited constructor look used in the new syntax the same way as in the old one?

Comment: Only the word changed. The implied constructor was a function with the same name as the contract. The new method is the keyword `constructor`.

Comment: I understand that, but the inherited contract is still initialized with its own name? So in my example with `constructor(_var1, _var2) public NameOfInheritedContr (_var1, _var2) { ... }`

Comment: I get you, now. Yes. The functions are all called `function constructor()`. The inheritance arguments syntax uses the name of the `contract`.

Comment: Sorry, but I still have a question. What difference would it make if I'd put `DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, TOKEN_DECIMALS)` inside `{ ... }` of the constructor. Wouldn't it be the same? (see my edited question)